# How to upgrade SSIS packages (having script tasks) created in VS 2013 to VS 2015 after SQL server upgrade from 2014 to 2016

Tags: sql-server

We recently had SQL server upgrade from SQL 2014 to SQL 2016 and now need to upgrade SSIS packages accordingly to support to the existing SQL server version.

I had tried upgrading the package by opening the Solution in Visual studio 2015 and selecting the Deploy target server to SQL 2016 and it was successful. But when I execute the package, the script task is failed with an error saying Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I also tried adding a new script task to the package in VS 2015 and copy pasted the same script from the original script task and then executed. But it failed again with the same error message

Could you please guide me how can I upgrade the SSIS package and execute them successfully.

Comment: There is no "upgrade" process for script tasks. VB.Net and C# haven't really changed in 2014 to 2016. I have Script tasks that are were created on BIDS and work just fine in SSDT 2016 (with no changes). *Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation* Could mean anything. I'd suggest adding error handling in your Script Task and getting an information/Warning messages to output the actual error(s) and where it occured. If you're interacting with certain drivers, or paths, i imagine you don't have the drivers install on the new server, or missing permissions. But that's a **guess**.

Comment: you better to debug the script and find where it through the exception. Or can you post your script here.  probably a reference issue.